What should I do if Spyder refuses to open?
I need to use spyder in Anaconda for a final class project in Python. When I tried to open it it started loading, then just stopped and refused to open. There were no error messages or anything, it just refused to open.
I tried multiple things to resolve this; one suggested by my teacher, and the other found on another post in Stackoverflow. Neither of them resolved the problem.
(a) I created a new environment in Anaconda. This had the same problem.
(b) I uninstalled and reinstalled a few packages in Qt Console, including sip, pyqt, and spyder using the conda install sip, conda install pyqt, and conda update spyder commands.
(c) I uninstalled and reinstalled tornado.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Are you opening spyder by selecting it in the anaconda navigator, or from an anaconda command prompt. If you havn't tried the latter, please do so, as you might get more information about errors occuring

Also include a conda info and conda list output for the environment from which you try to start spyder

@FlyingTeller How do I use the anaconda command prompt? Is it conda open spyder?

To make sure: are you using windows? In that case, there is a shortcut in your startmenu under Anaconda. If you are using linux/macOS then just use your normal terminal

No, I am not using Windows, I am using Mac.
